# Why and when should you typecast variables in PHP

Tags: php, casting

Given this declaration:

```
(string)$my_string = 'Hello world';
```

****vs****

```
$my_string = 'Hello world';
```

**or***

```
 (int)$my_int = 1;


 $my_int = 1;
```

Is there an advantage over the first way of defining a string variable in PHP?

Comment: I'm not sure it even has any effect in this case. If you want to store the type casted value I'd expect `$my_string = (string) 'Hello world';`, but my PHP is a bit rusty, so don't listen to me.

Comment: @FelixKling the syntax that I wrote out actually compiled. I haven't checked if it works with your syntax yet.

Comment: I don't doubt that it compiles but I was always under the impression that `(foo) bar` *returns* something. Like the conditional operator does. Some people us it for side effects and write `foo ? bar : baz;` and ignore the return value. In that case it would not be better at all (not saying that my version is any good, why cast a string as a string? ;)). Maybe that's the point though: If you know the type of a value, you don't have to cast it. Why would you? It already has that type. I can paint black and white stripes on a zebra, but does it make sense (if it's not an albino)?

Comment: Yeah I agree. I was just thinking about this because I just finished a C++ class, and it is way more precise than PHP. I want to try to make my PHP code as efficient as possible.

Comment: Ah... statically vs dynamically typed languages it is then :) Even with type casting, you don't add any information to the *variable*. The variable will hold any value no matter which type. Type casting is only for converting the type of the *value* to another type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "typecasting" code doesn't actually accomplish anything.

`(type) $var = literal` does this:

1. Assign literal value to `$var` with the literal value's native type.
2. "Return" (as an expression) the value of `$var` cast to the desired type.

The type of `$var` remains unchanged.

For example:

```php
var_dump((string) $s = 1);
var_dump($s);
```

Output is:

```
string(1) "1"
int(1)
```

So there is no point to this syntax.  Typecasting with a literal is almost certainly pointless.

However it can be useful to force a variable to be a certain type, for example: `$intvar = (int) $var;`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an advantage over the first way

yes. second one is more concise.

> What are the advantages of typecasting variables in PHP

casting it to the expected type.
you seldom need it with strings though.
and with variable definitions you don't need it at all.